# Strategy for filtering variables and building a minified JS distribution artifact for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I come from a Java/Maven background where you would create WAR files to deploy. Maven provides the ability to "filter" files during the build and replace variables at build time with targeted information for the environment you're deploying to.

Now I am working in Node.js and I was wondering if there's a similar facility and best practice you can use in Node.js whereby I could minify my javascript into a single file but at the same time filter variables respective to the environment I'm deploying to.

For instance, there's an app_name config that I'd like to be environment specific:

```
  exports.config = {
     app_name : ['$APPNAME-$ENV'],
     license_key : 'xxx',
     logging : {
       level : '$DEBUG_LEVEL'
     }
  };
```

So I'd like to be able to update all the $ variables above with environment specific variables into a separate minified JS file.  It seems like I'd have to copy the files into a staging area, do a string replace on the variables and then minify.  Does that seem reasonable or are there any recommendations on how to best accomplish this in the Node world?

Comment: I do what you're suggesting, string replace and use Google CC to minify.

Comment: What's the reason to minify a Node.js script?

Comment: @Bergi - to reduce the size and consolidate the code for distribution into one artifact I could place in our release repo.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - what tools are you using to copy and string replace? Grunt??

Comment: Nothing as fancy as that, just a PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing with [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) to accomplish what was talked about above (clean, copy, string-replace, JSHint, and Google CC to minify).  I posted a more complete reading of this [here](http://loutilities.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/grunt-targeted-environment-builds-for-node-js-jshint-closure-compiler/) for those interested in a deeper dive.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            clean: ["dist"],
            copy: {
                build: {
                    files: [
                        {src: ['./**/*.js', './*.json', './stackato.yml', './README.md', './nunit.js', './test/**/*', '!./dist/**/*', '!./node_modules/**/*', '!./Gruntfile.js'], dest: 'dist/'}
                    ]
                }
            },
            'string-replace': {
                dev: {
                    files: {
                        "dist/": ["newrelic.js", "stackato.yml", "package.json"]
                    },
                    options: {
                        replacements: [
                            {
                                pattern: '$APPNAME',
                                replacement: "services-people"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$VERSION',
                                replacement: "1.0.6"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: 'server.js',
                                replacement: "server.min.js"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$ENV',
                                replacement: "DEV"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$PDS_PWD',
                                replacement: ""
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$INSTANCES',
                                replacement: "1"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$NEWRELIC_TRACE_LVL',
                                replacement: "trace"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                prod: {
                    files: {
                        "dist/": ["newrelic.js", "stackato.yml", "package.json"]
                    },
                    options: {
                        replacements: [
                            {
                                pattern: '$APPNAME',
                                replacement: "services-people"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$VERSION',
                                replacement: "1.0.6"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: 'server.js',
                                replacement: "server.min.js"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$ENV',
                                replacement: "prod"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$PDS_PWD',
                                replacement: ""
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$INSTANCES',
                                replacement: "2"
                            },
                            {
                                pattern: '$NEWRELIC_TRACE_LVL',
                                replacement: "info"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            jshint: {
                options: {
                    curly: true,
                    eqeqeq: true,
                    eqnull: true,
                    strict: true,
                    globals: {
                        jQuery: true
                    },
                    ignores: ['dist/test/**/*.js']
                },
                files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'dist/**/*.js']
            },
            nodeunit: {
              all: ['dist/test/*-tests.js']
            },
            'closure-compiler': {
                build: {
                    closurePath: '.',
                    js: 'dist/**/*.js',
                    jsOutputFile: 'dist/server.min.js',
                    maxBuffer: 500,
                    options: {
                        compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
                        language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
                        debug: false
//                        formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-closure-compiler');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

        // Default task(s).
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'copy:build', 'string-replace:dev', 'jshint', 'closure-compiler:build']);
        grunt.registerTask('prod', ['clean', 'copy:build', 'string-replace:prod', 'jshint', 'closure-compiler:build']);
    };
})();
```

On the CLI, you can just use "grunt" to spin up the DEV version or "grunt prod" to build the PROD version.